# Assigning array reference to session variable

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am trying to assign an array reference to the php `$_SESSION` variable, but cannot get it to work.

Consider a simple form:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <FORM action="post.php" method="post">
      User name: <INPUT type="text" name="user"><br>
         <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit">
      </FORM>
   </body>
</html>
```

where `post.php` is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
   $data=array();
   $data['user']=$_POST['user'];
   $data['pass']='xxxx';
   $uid="1234";
  $_SESSION[$uid] = &$data;
   header( 'HTTP/1.1 303 See Other' );
   header( 'Location: post.php?id='.$uid );
   exit();
}
if( isset( $_GET[ 'id' ] )) {
   $uid=$_GET[ 'id' ];
   $user=$_SESSION[$uid]['user'];
} else {
   exit();
}
?>
<html>
   <body>
    <?php
       echo "<p>Username: ".$user."</p>";
    ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

I get an empty username in the resulting `post.php?id=1234` file.. What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't assign anything to session by reference: on the next request when you access session, the variable won't exist anymore so the reference is pointing to nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you get empty username.

The variable is 'deleted' after the script, so the references points to 'junk'.

Simply assign the array to the variable.

```
$_SESSION[$uid] = $data;
```

You can't use 'numeric values' for session variables. Session mechanism uses variable registering. A variable named '1234' is invalid because it can't start with numeric value. So the session can't create the variable because it is 'invalid'.

You have to prefix the numeric value or use another array like:

```
$_SESSION["users"][$uid] = $data;
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course.. But the field is still empty.. If I take `var_dump` of `$_SESSION` I get: `array(2) { ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["count"]=> int(0) }`.. (The count field is probably from some earlier debugging using the same session, I do not know where the `error` field comes from).. Maybe I have to write a loop to assign each field of `$data` to the `$_SESSION` variable separately?